# Swagger-ui cannot access JS scripts

Tags: swagger-ui

I followed the [swagger-ui installation](http://swagger.io/docs/#swagger-ui-documentation-29) and I cannot get this work. The problem is that java-script files are not accessible. It seems that the names are wrong - index.html expects `SwaggerUiStandalonePreset.js` and in **/dist** directory there is only `swagger-ui-standalone-preset.js`.

I thought that this is a problem, but the [disclaimer on github](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/blob/master/dist/index.html) explains:

```
<!-- don't be alarmed, these don't match what's in dist, because webpack-dev-server serves them in memory. -->
<script src="/dist/SwaggerUIBundle.js"> </script>
```

What to do now?

Answer (score 2):

This situation seems to be a bug in new version of swagger-ui.

If you want to make this application working just move **/dist** directory to parent directory of your http server and rename following files:

- swagger-ui-bundle.js to SwaggerUIBundle.js
- swagger-ui-standalone-preset.js to SwaggerUIStandalonePreset.js

Comment: Thanks! Well it is strange mock-up -> I can confirm that it works! For now I'll use the old version (as I described in other answer) and move to 3.0 later.

Comment: @kzygmans It works for me but i am getting a validator error at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution that works for me - current GitHub master is Swagger 3.0, which is very fresh (appears to be one day old) and appears to be broken. Probably some time is needed that documentation will be adapted for 3.0 version.

I downloaded [Swagger 2.x](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/archive/2.x.zip) version and everything works following the [swagger-ui installation guide](http://swagger.io/docs/#swagger-ui-documentation-29).

[image: Swagger GitHub repo]