# How to get Swagger UI to work based on documentation guide? (even the example)

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui

I am trying to use Swagger UI to document our node.js API, so I went to http://swagger.io/docs/, down to Swagger UI Documentation -> Usage, to find this [image]

Now, this is not the only place that provides these instructions, there are dozens of blogs & tutorials saying the same thing, so that's exactly what I did.

Cloned the repo, went into `/dist/` and ran the `/dist/index.html` and all I get is an empty page with an error:
[image]

I'm slowly going crazy now as I can't find anything about it and literally every place I looked just has the same, copied, instructions with nothing else provided (like what could go wrong? you just open a file...)

Any help or explanations are much appreciated!

P.S. for some reason opening the `/public/index.html` works (mentioned nowhere on the www)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is bug in new version of swagger-UI. This is fresh release and they are still modifying and fixing bugs.

Look here: [Swagger-ui cannot access JS scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42926158/swagger-ui-cannot-access-js-scripts). This seems to be similar problem, maybe it will help you.