# Setup of Swagger-UI 3.0.X

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

Swagger-UI has recently updated to a [3.0.X version](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/tree/v3.0.3/dist)

In the past, the dist folder contained a lib/css/etc folder, and I was able to successfully copy that file structure to launch my webapp. However, copying the current structure, I get 404 errors trying to get https://localhost:17070/dist/SwaggerUIBundle.js

What is the right way to set up the new version of Swagger-UI?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swagger-ui cannot access JS scripts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42926158/swagger-ui-cannot-access-js-scripts)

Comment: Have you tried deploying the contents of the `dist` folder from the latest master?  I did this today and it worked well for me.  The Swagger UI team has closed lots of issues over the past few days.

Comment: Yes, this is with 3.0.3

Comment: Since you have the latest version, I don't think this is a duplicate question.  However, I don't have an answer for you.  I deployed the latest distribution on my HTTP server and it worked for me.  Also, it's no longer necessary to run Swagger UI from `/dist` and you don't have to rename `swagger-ui-bundle.js`, etc.