# Hosting Swagger UI 3.0 in ASP NET Web application

Tags: asp.net, swagger-ui

I am currently trying to host SWAGGER UI in a stand alone application so I can input my restful URLS and get the documentation.

I have downloaded the zip from the repo 
https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui I have ONLY copied the DIST folder (since that is all I need) and placed it in my views folder re named as swagger, picture below:

[image: SwaggerFileStructure]

My Controller method down below:

[image]

The issue I am having is that the index.html view is being returned but none of the files within it are NOT being found:

[image]

I keep reading online that in march of this year the new 3.0 version came out with some bugs, but I would have imagined that these were fixed.

I tried renaming some javascript files as mentioned in this thread, this did not work.

[Swagger-ui cannot access JS scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42926158/swagger-ui-cannot-access-js-scripts)

Does anybody have any ideas on how to fix this matter? Do we need to revert back to the 2.0 version?

Comment: Why download a zip? Why not use NuGet and follow the directions [here](http://wmpratt.com/swagger-and-asp-net-web-api-part-1/)?

Comment: @mason I am following the official documentation to host the SwaggerUI https://swagger.io/docs/swagger-tools/#swagger-ui-documentation-29 it states to download the latest version and copy the DIST folder into your app.

Comment: @Lostaunaum static files belong into the wwwroot folder, not the views folder. The views folder is for razor view files which are being executed by  the razor engine. You can't hotlink into the views folder as it is not exposed directly while the wwwroot folder is.

Comment: @xen Thank you I will implement that fix.